# Integrating only some changes from another branch's latest commit

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

Assume a branch named **A**.
From **A**, a new branch is created named **B**.

**B** evolves involving creation of **ONE** commit about creation of 3 files:

- **File1**
- **File2**
- **File3**

while **A** remains unaltered.

I want to create a branch named **C** from **A**, integrating **ONLY** **File1** and **File2** from **B**.

What is a good practice to handle this case, without any basic and ugly copy/paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting on branch A:

```
git checkout -b C
git cherry-pick -n sha1_from_commit_on_B
```

The `-n` option is to cherry-pick the changes without creating a commit, it is necessary here because you don't want all the changes from the commit on B.

```
git add File1 File2
git commit -m "commit message"
```

Comment: This answer would benefit greatly from explaining what the `-n` does and why it is important.

Comment: What about 2 commits ahead, if I want to cherry-pick some files among those 2 commits.  It seems that targeting a specific commit from cherry-pick doesn't present files from the other ahead. Should it be possible with the concept of cherry-pick ranges? I'm reading about..

Comment: I succeeded with "git checkout -p <commit from B>".